# save excel file using FileSaver.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, export-to-excel, filesaver.js

I am trying to export data to excel in angular js

1) User clicks a button
2) Data in $scope.myArray gets saved to excel file.

I tried

```
var blob = new Blob($scope.myArray , {
    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
});
saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
};
```

It prompts to open the excel file.
But whenever I try to open it, it says the file format or file extension is not valid.

Any Help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following code that will help you to create an excel file for you.

```
var result = ["Item 1", "Item 3"];
const myJsonString = JSON.stringify(result);
const blob = new Blob([myJsonString], {
  type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"
});
saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/mdshohelrana/pen/wNbgrO)

Comment: $scope.myArray must be string type, wait

Comment: It Worked, one more ques. It shows lots of [object Object] to me, myArray contains following data  .....[Object { IdeaNumber=31,  Description="amit1",  Department="RBVH/ETI1",  more...}, Object { IdeaNumber=32,  Description="Testing nutshell",  Department="RBEI/BSW2",  more...}, Object { IdeaNumber=35,  Description="Testing nutshell",  Department="RBEI/BSW2",  more...}]

Comment: One more! now it shows in one row ..any help to show in tabluar?? [{"IdeaNumber":31,"Description":"amit1","Department":"RBVH/ETI1","Status":"Implemented","StatusColor":"idea-status-implemented","$$hashKey":"object:11"},{"IdeaNumber":32,"Description":"Testing nutshell","Department":"RBEI/BSW2","Status":"Implemented","StatusColor":"idea-status-implemented","$$hashKey":"object:12"},{"IdeaNumber":35,"Description":"Testing nutshell","Department":"RBEI/BSW2","Status":"Waiting for implementation","StatusColor":"idea-status-waiting-for-implementation","$$hashKey":"object:13"},

Comment: I do not know brother

Comment: @Amit Kumar have you completed multiline export of data ?

Comment: My data is like ['1','2','3']. The final result will be only one cell with data ["1","2","3"]. Can anybody give an example to show what's inside myArray? Thanks.

Comment: The way I fixed the inline JSON issue was to dynamically convert it to a html table using jquery.The SaveAs does work pretty good with html structures, but I was not able to make it work with JSON

Comment: @Shohel regarding my question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943003/encoding-csv-clrf-into-newlines), how can I ensure CLRF encoding is working on csv files (whether excel or google sheets). It's not displaying the spaces / multilines I'm expecting when I open the CSV

Comment: Please add a more comprehensive answer which everyone reading can benefit from. Please declare what's `result`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 csv = ['name','md5','desc']
  _.map $scope.trustFileList, (_file) ->
    csv.push "\n#{_file.name}"
    csv.push _file.md5
    csv.push _file.desc

  blob = new Blob([csv], {
    type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  });

  saveAs(blob, "TrustFileWhiteList.xls");
```